# How can I load/start my device driver as early as possible on system bootup

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, boot

I have a KMDF device driver that has an inf file and I would like to know how would I start/load my device driver before any other application or kernel mode drivers on **boot up** but load after the kernel has completely loaded ? My device driver targets Windows 8.1 at the moment have yet to ensure compatibility with Windows 10/11. Would creating a service be the only way to ensure that this driver loads first ?

Thanks

Comment: What if another driver also wanted to be the first before all other drivers?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what type of driver this is and why you need to be loaded so early...

Comment: @Anders I am using a CALLBACK routine in my driver that gets called whenever a process gets created so I need to catch all such instances of this. The sooner my driver loads the less chance that I will miss a process that is newly created.

Comment: Well, do you care about system processes like smss.exe?

Comment: @Anders yes I do but at this point I'm not sure whether my code (CALLBACK i.e. PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine) is able to catch new processes created by this process. Can you elaborate a little about this process ?

Comment: smss is the first user-mode process. It starts long before services.exe. I think boot start and maybe even system start drivers starts before it. Read more about this in the Windows Internals book.